# raw SQL vs ORM If I already know SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am currently using PostgreSQL along with nodejs.
So far, I have developed using raw SQL with `pg` driver.
I'm expecting my service to have quite a lot of records in the near future.(10k+)

I have done some research on SQL vs ORM as it is not a new issue.
From what I understood,

SQL has better performance,
ORM enhances code readability, reduces code length and easier to learn than SQL.

This research http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1014983/FULLTEXT02 shows quite drastic performance difference between raw SQL and ORM when row count increases. Because the research has been carried out with `Laravel ORM`, I am aware that the result can be different with `nodejs ORM sequelize`.

My code is quite long because I have SQL strings in my functions. If I already know how to write SQL, should I switch to ORM?

Added: 
If I were to implement ORM, because I have some complex queries joining and aggregating several tables, would it be a bad choice if I use ORM for simple `SELECT` and `INSERT` and raw SQL for complex queries?

Comment: [What ORMs have taught me: just learn SQL](https://wozniak.ca/blog/2014/08/03/What-ORMs-have-taught-me-just-learn-SQL/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced something similar recently and will share my experience with you.

I have a mostly DB background (SQL / stored procedures), with a little UI experience.  I wrote my first web-app from scratch last year using Postgres and Django and jumped into writing the whole DB interface myself, because that's all I knew.  I had never used a built-in ORM before and didn't even know what it was or its benefits.

It was exciting and fun at first, since you have control over all the DB operations and also get a better understanding of how all the code works.  After a while, though, I realized some of the cons:

- most of the Django / Python modules are designed to use Django's ORM.  I had a hard time getting a lot of them to work with my custom interface.  One example is they expected to have an "id" column as the PK for all related tables.  Another issue was no support for multi-column PKs.
- if you create a new object, you need to create multiple sets of stored procedures / functions to manage them; it got tedious after a while
- you'll have to create your own upgrade scripts if your schema changes and you want to upgrade an installation that already has data

One of the main advantages of building your own interface is that you have complete control over the physical database model (i.e. you can pick the indexes / keys, custom naming convention, etc).

If you hadn't mentioned the concern about performance, then I would have suggested to just use the provided ORM since it will integrate more easily with other modules and is easier to handle support for new objects.

It really depends on how important these factors are to you:

- development time
- maintenance
- performance
- customizability (i.e. custom SQL)
- ability to interface with other modules

If performance and customizability are a big concern and you don't plan to incorporate 3rd party modules, then I'd look at writing the interface yourself.  Otherwise, I'd say it's easier to just use the ORM.